# Compare-Object: PassThru parameter alters input variable

Tags: powershell

Easiest to explain this issue with a code snippet...

```
Clear-Host

$refObj = New-Object System.Object
$refObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ObjectMember1 -Value 123

$diffObj = New-Object System.Object
$diffObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ObjectMember1 -Value 456


Write-Output 'Before 1st comparison...'
$refObj | Get-Member | ? { $_.MemberType  -eq 'NoteProperty' } | Select *


$x = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -IncludeEqual

Write-Output 'After 1st comparison...'
$refObj | Get-Member | ? { $_.MemberType  -eq 'NoteProperty' } | Select *


$y = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -PassThru -IncludeEqual

Write-Output 'After 2nd comparison...'
$refObj | Get-Member | ? { $_.MemberType  -eq 'NoteProperty' } | Select *
```

... and the results (appears to be the same in PS versions 3 and 5, haven't tested any others) ...

[image: Query results]

What I'm struggling to understand is why the inclusion of the -PassThru parameter is altering one of the input variables, by adding on an additional parameter.

In addition to struggling to understand why this is happening, I'd like to avoid it. Is there a way of specifying the output variable for the Compare-Object cmdlet without altering the input variables?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It's clear to me now that the question wasn't clear enough. To make this more straightforward....

```
$y = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -PassThru -IncludeEqual
```

With the above, how do I stop SideIndicator being added to $refObj, and add it to $y instead? There doesn't seem to be an -OutVariable option for Compare-Object, is there another way I can do this?

EDIT 2:
Turns out there is an -OutVariable option for Compare-Object, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -IncludeEqual -PassThru -OutVariable $objComparisonResults
```

I would expect data in $objComparisonResults, but no data is saved in this variable.

Answer (score 1):

`Compare-Object` always adds the `SideIndicator` NoteProperty. Have a look at the objects produced. PowerShell produces object, not flat text to be parsed. Using `-PassThru` simply caused it to appear in the console output.

```
Clear-Host
$logfile = 'C:\src\t\pt.txt'
if (Test-Path -Path $logfile) { Remove-Item -Path $logfile }

$refObj = New-Object System.Object
$refObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ObjectMember1 -Value 123

$diffObj = New-Object System.Object
$diffObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ObjectMember1 -Value 456


'Before 1st comparison...' | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii

$refObj | Get-Member | ? { $_.MemberType  -eq 'NoteProperty' } | Select * | gm |
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii


$x = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -IncludeEqual | gm |
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii

'After 1st comparison...' | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii

$refObj | Get-Member | ? { $_.MemberType  -eq 'NoteProperty' } | Select * | gm |
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii


$y = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -PassThru -IncludeEqual | gm |
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii

'After 2nd comparison...' | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii

$refObj | Get-Member | ? { $_.MemberType  -eq 'NoteProperty' } | Select * | gm |
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: Thank you for your response lit. I don't think I worded the question properly, as my main issue isn't that SideIndicator is added to an object, but rather being able to control which object it's added to. I'll edit the question.

Comment: When using `-PassThru`, the `SideIndicator` property is added to each object in the result. The original ReferenceObject and DifferenceObject are unchanged. If the object is new in the DifferenceObject, it will be in the result with a SideIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Instead of trying to save the Compare-Object results in a variable in this way...

```
$y = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -PassThru -IncludeEqual
```

... can save the results this way ...

```
$y = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1 -DifferenceObject $file2 -Property $properties1 -IncludeEqual)
```

This second way, the output is saved in $y, and as -PassThru was skipped, we should avoid changes being saved back to an input variable.

As a further refinement, can use Tee-Object to store the output in a variable, which also allows us to control whether the Compare-Object output is automatically displayed on screen (Out-Null in the command below means that this is output is suppressed):

```
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $refObj -DifferenceObject $diffObj -IncludeEqual) | Tee-Object -Variable y | Out-Null
```